# writing XMLInternalDocument or XMLAbstractDocument classes from r

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I am new to working with xmls in r and am trying to read in, edit, and write an xml. The xml object is stored as a `Classes 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr>`

```
data <- xmlParse(file = "Path\\to\\my\\file.xml")
str(data)
Classes 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr>
```

I then make some changes to one of the nodes

```
invisible(replaceNodes(data[["//descript//abstract/text()"]], newXMLTextNode( "New Text Here")))
```

When I try to write the edited .xml

```
write_xml(data, file = "Path\\to\\my\\NEW_file.xml")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("write_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'write_xml' applied to an object of class "c('XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument')"
```

As far as I can tell, these object classes provide a handle/reference to a C-level data structure for large xmls ([link here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/XML/versions/3.99-0.5/topics/XMLInternalDocument-class)), and I have not been able to find an example that writes them from r, ideally overwriting the previous xml that was read in.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try saveXML from the XML package:

```
XML::saveXML(data, "NEW_file.xml")
```